# how can modified the footnote boxes size so that fit into my body of the text and looks better in printing

Tags: formatting

[image]

Hi I am a beginner of Latex, and i met a problem such that the footnote has conquered so much space at the bottom of page, for which i want to change it to a smaller size so that to fit into the body of the text. thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. At the moment it's hard to tell what will solve your problem, it will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See if it is related. It's about the space between footnotes and the bottom of the page : https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5001

Answer (score 1):

1) Without a MWE I  cannot guarantee, but probably add `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` in the preamble will reduce the space between the number of page and the matrix. Moreover maths in display mode add vertical spaces and produce a bigger font that inline math mode, so this will take less pace:

```
\footnote{
... columns:

\hfil
$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]$}
```

2) On the other hand, to obtain a smaller font size, simply use  `\footnote{\scriptsize  foo}` or  `\footnote{\tiny  foo}` ...

... **but I would not do it**:

If your "foo" is very important, it should be in the main text with a 10-12pt font instead of  punishing the reader with so much text with the default small font for footnotes (`\footnotesize`), or worse, even smaller.

If that "foo" is not so important, surely it can be resumed to a readable note with few words (were you surely can left the default `\footnotesize`) or remove it completely.